# Exercise 1.5.D (c) in the book of Ryszard Engelking (General Topology)

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

A couter example: I am trying to solve the exercise 1.5.D (c) in the book of Ryszard Engelking (General Topology). Namely, one has to look for a Hausdorff space such that $2^{d(X)}<w(X)$.

The book gives the following hint. Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$. For each $z\in X$ and $r$ positive number we let $C(z,r)$ be the circle of radius $r$ and center at $z$. For all real number $t$, we let $D_t:=\lbrace (s,t)\in X : s\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace$ and $\mathcal{F}:=\lbrace A\subseteq X: \forall t\in\mathbb{R}, A\cap D_t\text{ if finite}\rbrace$.
Now, $X$ is endowed with the topology generated by the family $\mathcal{B}$ consisting of all sets of the form $C(z,r)\setminus A$ where $A\in\mathcal{F}$.

Is is obvious that $d(X)=\aleph_0$. So, one needs to show that if $\mathcal{B}'\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ and $|\mathcal{B}'|=\mathfrak{c}$, then there is an open set which cannot be written as a union of some sets in $\mathcal{B}'$. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B’}=\{B_\alpha:\alpha<\frak c\}$. By transfinite induction, for each $\alpha<\frak c$ pick a point $(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)\in B_\alpha\setminus \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} D_{y_\beta}$. Then the set $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(x_\alpha, y_\alpha):\alpha<\frak c\}$  is open, but it is not a union of any subfamily of $\mathcal{B’}$.